# django-celery PeriodicTask getting last run time using DatabaseScheduler

Tags: python, django, celery

using django-celery, with the backend `djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler`, I need to access the last run time for a `celery.task.PeriodicTask`

The old docs for [version 2.4](https://django-celery.readthedocs.org/en/2.4/reference/djcelery.models.html) say there is a class `PeriodicClassMeta` which has the metadata for the task, including `last_run`.  However the docs for `django-celery` don't include any usage information for the models or how to set up `PeriodicTasks`.

So, my question is, how do you setup `PeriodicTasks` in django-celery, using the `DatabaseScheduler` backend and access the metadata related to the last run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this task is only run as a periodic task and that task runtimes are shorter than the spacing of the periodic tasks.

```
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask, TaskMeta

last_run = PeriodicTask.objects.only('last_run_at')\
                               .get(task=task_name).last_run_at
task_meta = TaskMeta.objects.filter(task_id=task_name, date_done__gte=last_run)\
                            .order_by('date_done').only('meta')[:1][0].meta
```